# Joining two large hdf5 files based on single column in python

Tags: python, hdf5

I'm trying to join two hdf5 files on the disk based on a single column and then perform some calculations. I guess I can use dask but it is slow for my task and would like to know if there are any other alternatives in h5py package or bcolz package that I use.

TIA

Comment: I'd definitely do it using h5py.  Are you able to control how the files are written, or they are already written and you can only control how to read them?

Comment: One file is downloaded from api in json format. The API has paging option and other file is downloaded from mysql server. I can control how the files are written.

Comment: @JohnZwinck. Any idea on how I can do with h5py.

Comment: The way this site works is you write the code, and if you get stuck, you post the code you have with a description of why you're stuck.